# When is a product under "active development"

Tags: frameworks

I am currently working on a project in which we will use a framework. I want the framework to be under active development but, when can you say that it is?

I know you can say it's "active" when there has been a commit to the source code in x amount of months.
Another way to see it is if it has an active community around it with support. 
Yet another way to see it is if the developer hasn't quit the project, the problem with this one is that developers usually don't announce this.

I do wonder if someone can provide a clear set of standards an "active" project should adhere to.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want it to be on "active" development in the fist place.
Find a framework that is realiable, has a good documentation and is well supported.

A project can be on "active" developement and still be bad. Don't make your choices only on how much code the developers commit or that can of stuff.
Worry about quality, reputation...

And btw if you gave more information about what kind of framework you're looking for, I'm sure we could even give you some recommendation ;)

Comment: At the moment I'm looking into cross-platform development frameworks for Windows Phone and Android (and well, kind of iOS but any framework that supports the first 2 will support the latter). I am trying to filter down frameworks (which include JavaScript frameworks). The problem is doing this in a way that I can justify my choice. The even bigger problem is actually defining it hence the question.